# Bash find and replace in a file isn't working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to replace all of the IP addresses (except 127.0.0.1) in a file ("/etc/hosts") with a different IP that is defined earlier as a variable (n). Here is what I have:

```
grep -v '127.0.0.1' /etc/hosts | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | xargs -0 sed -i '$n'
```

If it helps, the default assignment for the variable is 192.168.2.62.

I'm a little bit of a newb, so whatever insight you have would be great, thanks!

Comment: `grep -v` discards the whole line , not a particular string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below Perl one-liner.

```
$ n="192.168.2.62"
$ echo '192.1.1.6 127.0.0.1 173.75.3.5' | perl -pe 's/\b(?!127\.0\.0\.1)[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\b/'"$n/g"
192.168.2.62 127.0.0.1 192.168.2.62
```

Add inline edit `-i` parameter to save the changes made.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single `sed` command for that:

```
sed -r '/127.0.0.1/!{s/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/'"$n"'/}' file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

```
/127.0.0.1/                    Regex pattern
!                              The following block gets executed if 
                               the  previous regex does not match
{                              Start of block
s                              Start of `substitute` command
/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/  Regex pattern to match an ip 
                               (simplified!)
/'"$n"'/                       Replacement IP. Interpolation of $n
}                              End of block
```

If you are sure the commands works as expected add the `-i` option. With the `-i` option `sed` will modify the original file (*file.txt*)

Comment: and this applies to the whole line. ie, it would discard all the lines which contain `127.0.0.1`

Comment: What if the file contains  a line like `192.1.1.6 127.0.0.1 173.75.3.5` ?

Comment: Generally a good point! However, the `/etc/hosts` file will not contain multiple IPs per line.. (Probably except in comments)

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks hek2mgl!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk command instead of all piped commands:

```
awk -v n="$n" 'NF>1 && $1 != "127.0.0.1" && $1 ~ /^\d{1,3}\./ {$1=n} 1' /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on OSX:

```
find /etc/hosts -type f -exec sed -i '' '/^127\.0\.0\.1/! s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/192.192.192.192/g' {} \;
```

For Linux the following should work:

```
find /etc/hosts -type f -exec sed -i '/^127\.0\.0\.1/! s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/192.192.192.192/g' {} \;
```

Not sure if you need extra slashes before curly braces in Linux.

`/^127\.0\.0\.1/!` = Only do replacement on lines not starting with 127.0.0.1